# Blank subprocess.check_output in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess

I am trying to clear Redis cache using the following command:

```
redis-cli -h cacheprod01 EVAL "for i, name in ipairs(redis.call('keys', KEYS[1])) do redis.call('DEL', name); end" 1 39_ras*
```

When I run it in Windows command prompt, I get this response:

```
(nil)
```

However, when I try to do the same thing using the following Python code, the output is blank, even though the code does clear the cache:

```
import subprocess
output = subprocess.check_output('''redis-cli -h cacheprod01 EVAL "for i, name in ipairs(redis.call('keys', KEYS[1])) do redis.call('DEL', name); end" 1 39_ras*''', shell=True)
print output
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I get a response using Python? I am using Python 2.7.

Comment: have you tried adding `stderr=subprocess.STDOUT` to capture standard error stream as well?

Comment: If you mean running it like this, it still gives me a blank response `output = subprocess.check_output('''redis-cli -h cacheprod01 EVAL "for i, name in ipairs(redis.call('keys', KEYS[1])) do redis.call('DEL', name); end" 1 39_ras*''', stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)`